# Intellij could not compile gradle project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am new to the Gradle build system. I wanted to use gradle with IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 Community Edition.

- I created a gradle project using wizard.
- Created a simple javafx application
- I tried to build the project and got an error

> Error:gradle-resources-test:aMaze_test: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/util/ReaderInputStream

## build.gradle

```
group 'aryanware'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

## AmazeWindow.java

```
package aryanware.amaze;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AmazeWindow extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

## Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

I don't have any good knowledge of how gradle works. So I am not able to resolve this error by myself.

Comment: does building from the command line work? (Run `./gradlew build`)

Answer (score 0):

I've checked it in forums and seams to be an Intellij issue. Suggested workaround is invalidating the cache.

[IntelliJ/Invalidate caches](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147146)